# Git - error: Untracked working tree file would be overwritten by merge. Aborting

Tags: git

I am new to git and left to work with live server.

After few successful `git pull` actions, on the latest one I got this error:

```
error: Untracked working tree file 
'www/files/userphotos/styles/100x100/noavatar.png' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting
```

I tried `git stash`, but nothing happen - the error on git pull is still there.

How can I perform `git pull` and not mess anything on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do git add before the git stash

```
# Add the file to the staging area
git add . -A (alias for git add . && git add -u .)

# stash changes
git stash

# opull server updates
git pull
```

---

#### ***`Use git worktree`***

***`git worktree`*** allow you to work on different branches at the same time,
Here you can see that one folder is "dirty" while the second one isn't

They both using the same (single) repository

[image]

---

If you use rebase later on:

- Note: ([Since Git 2.7](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.7.0.txt))
  you can also use the `git rebase [--no]-autostash` as well.

Comment: `git add -A` is probably more correct, since `git add *` won't catch everything when new files exist in already-added subdirectories.

Comment: I agree. its better to use the -A

Comment: I performed both git add -A and git add *, and then git stash, git pull. The error is still showing.

Comment: `git add - A .` - add the `.` to the command and stand in the root folder of your project since add only add form current directory and down

Comment: Still nothing :/. Can't I somehow force pull?

Comment: You can clean the folder: `git clean -xfd && git clean -Xfd` or git `reset HEAD --hard` or `git checkout -f file_name`

Comment: Few options just choose one

Comment: Reset HEAD --hard did the job. Thanks for the help :)